# Add elements to array each time a particular function is called

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on an audio-recording application. Each time I stop the recording, I need to add the recording filename to an array.
Currently, only one element gets added and when I add the next element, I am not able to see the previous element that had been added.
Am I missing something?

```
func pushDummyUploadCell(pendingUploadModel: String) {

        var pendingUploadModels: [String] = []


                if !queueAllFailedRecordings {
                    pendingUploadModels.append(pendingUploadModel)
                    print("Queue:",pendingUploadModels.count,"elements:",[pendingUploadModels]) //each time returns 1
                } 

             else {
                pendingUploadModels = [pendingUploadModel]
            }

    }
```

I am calling this function once I stop the recording.

Comment: You need to move your pendingUploadModels array outside of the function. Each time you call the function a new array is created. That's why you are only seeing a single element in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to define your array as globle in your controller or class.

```
var pendingUploadModels: [String] = []

func pushDummyUploadCell(pendingUploadModel: String) {
            if !queueAllFailedRecordings {
                pendingUploadModels.append(pendingUploadModel)
                print("Queue:",pendingUploadModels.count,"elements:",[pendingUploadModels]) //each time returns 1
            } 

         else {
            pendingUploadModels = [pendingUploadModel]
        }
}
```